# ASP.net form SQL Server update from inputbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm trying to update a table in my SQL Server database with text from an input box on my site;

My table is `MemberSite.dbo.Users` and the columns within this table are:

```
ID (Auto incrementing) UserName, Password, ApiKey, VeriF
```

It's not updating my SQL Server table.

What I want this to do: take the input text and put it in my SQL Server table against the user that is logged in.

Here is some code `web.config` :

```
<add name="WRITER" 
     connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MembershipSite;User ID=test;Password=test!" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Backend to button click;

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;

    try
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE dbo.Users SET ApiKey = @API, VeriF = @verif WHERE UserName = @username";

        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WRITER"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        SqlParameter api = new SqlParameter();
        api.ParameterName = "@API";
        api.Value = APIinput;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(api);

        SqlParameter verif = new SqlParameter();
        verif.ParameterName = "@verif";
        verif.Value = Veri;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(verif);

        SqlParameter UserN = new SqlParameter();
        UserN.ParameterName = "@username";
        UserN.Value = User.Identity.Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(UserN);

        conn.Open();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn !=null)
            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I remove the ip address from your connection string, don't post information like this. I put localhost instead !

Comment: thank you!! i over looked that >.>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you *never* execute your command. Just add:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

after you open your connection.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command *automatically* instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually. Like;

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   // Set your CommandText
   // Add your parameters
   // Open your connection
   // Execute your command.
}
```

Comment: reason im choosing this answer as both were right is because it provided me with abit more information :)

Comment: Aslo to add to this i had to alter my SQLParamaters from api.Value = APIinput; to api.Value = APIinput.Text;

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` after `connection.Open()`. That's why the values are not updated